# Error installing nokogiri in ubuntu 14.0.4 (Ruby 1.8.7)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, installation, nokogiri

I'm trying to install the bundle(bundle install) in Ubuntu 14.0.4 installed Ruby 1.8.7.And it fails to install the bundle and displayed the error:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.4.7), and Bundler cannot
continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.4.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

so now I tried to get the nokogiri 1.4.7 with but it got failed showed

```
$ sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.4.7'
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

so again I tried to get this libxml2, but end up with the below message:

```
$ sudo gem install libxml2
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'libxml2' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: libxml4r


$ sudo gem install libxml4r
ERROR:  Error installing libxml4r
extconf failure: need libxml2.
```

I tried with the [reference](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html):

```
$ gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
$ bundle install
```

but still the same nokogiri error coming again. Don't have a clue how to continue. please help me!!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried the following commands and I've got it. Thanks to [Mr.Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381874/m-kumar)

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev
$ sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.4.7'

$ gem list nokogiri
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
nokogiri (1.4.7)
```

Answer (score 14):

in my case i need to install also this library.
`$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

Comment: Thank you! This was the one that worked for me after also trying libxml2-dev and libxslt-dev :)

Answer (score 8):

First, update the package index (package list).

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install libxml2.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Comment: If it answered your question, please mark it as the selected answer, and help others find it faster too =]

Answer (score 4):

After doing everything above and still getting the error what worked for me using **bundle config build with the system libraries**:

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and It helped, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
$ sudo gem install nokogiri --version 1.8.0
```

That will be all.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu server I also had to install `zlib1g-dev`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on ubuntu 18.04 and running `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev` helped me.